# boost::range::join many ranges in one custom call

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

The *Solution* section in [gnzlbg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422197/gnzlbg)'s SO question [boost::range::join for multiple ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14366576/2090317) implies it can join many ranges in one client code call to a custom function variadic template that calls `boost::join` and `boost::make_iterator_range`. According to that question, answer, and comments, the prior can join 2 ranges and the latter is needed to ensure the non-`const` overload of the prior is used. Any containers after the 2nd one are supposedly perfect-forwarded via `std::forward`. But my client code can only successfully call it with a maximum of 3 arguments. Anything more fails to compile. What’s wrong and how to fix it? And is there any Boost entity now that joins many ranges?

I’ve copied and pasted that OP’s implementation, editing it here only for whitespace readability and adding the relevant headers:

```
#include <utility>
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>

template<class C>
auto join(C&& c)
-> decltype(boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c)))
{
    return boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}

template<class C, class D, class... Args>
auto join(C&& c, D&& d, Args&&... args)
-> decltype
(
    boost::join
    (
        boost::join
        (
            boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c)),
            boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(d), std::end(d))
        ),
        join(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    )
)
{
    return boost::join
    (
        boost::join
        (
            boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c)),
            boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(d), std::end(d))
        ),
        join(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    );
}
```

and added my client code:

```
#include <deque>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::deque<int> deq { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::array<int, 4> stl_arr { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int c_arr[3] { 9, 10, 11 };
    std::vector<int> vec { 12, 13 };

    for (auto& i : join(deq, stl_arr, c_arr))
    {
        ++i;
        std::cout << i << ", ";         // OK, prints 1 thru 12
    }

    //join(deq, stl_arr, c_arr, vec);   // COMPILER ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things going on. The first is that the following declarations won’t work as intended:

```
template<class C>
auto join(C&& c)
-> decltype(boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c)));

template<class C, class D, class... Args>
auto join(C&& c, D&& d, Args&&... args)
-> decltype
(
    boost::join
    (
        boost::join
        (
            boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c)),
            boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(d), std::end(d))
        ),
        join(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    //  ^^^^-- (1)
    )
);
```

The crux of the matter is that at spot (1) the second overload of `join` is not in scope. With three arguments no problem manifests because the `Args` pack has length 1, so the resulting `join(std::forward<Arg0>(arg0))` expansion uses the first overload which *is* in scope.

With four arguments or more the resulting `join(std::forward<Arg0>(arg0), ..., std::forward<ArgN>(argN))` expansion needs the second overload but it is not in scope inside the late return type of the selfsame.

One way to fix that is to turn the set of function templates into a set of member function templates because class scope is more lenient:

```
struct join_type {
    template<class C>
    auto operator()(C&& c) const
    -> decltype(boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c)))
    {
        return boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
    }

    template<class C, class D, class... Args>
    auto operator()(C&& c, D&& d, Args&&... args) const
    -> decltype
    (
        boost::join
        (
            boost::join
            (
                boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c)),
                boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(d), std::end(d))
            ),
            (*this)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        )
    )
    {
        return boost::join
        (
            boost::join
            (
                boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(c), std::end(c)),
                boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(d), std::end(d))
            ),
            (*this)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );
    }
};

constexpr join_type join {};
```

Note that what matters is the class scope, not that we have chosen to use `operator()` as the name of our member function templates. You can just as well use static member function templates named `foo` and have a normal function template outside of the class that forwards to it.

---

Now we can expose the second problem in that the implementation is buggy and will only work with odd numbers of arguments! Even `join(a, b)` won’t work, but that bug could have been hidden previously by ADL (i.e. clients would end up effectively calling `boost::join(a, b)` which obviously works) (<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ae673c5d1be34a2)</kbd>).

Let’s rewrite the fold:

```
struct join_type {
    template<class C>
    auto operator()(C&& c) const
    -> decltype(boost::make_iterator_range(begin(c), end(c)))
    {
        return boost::make_iterator_range(begin(c), end(c));
    }

    template<typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest>
    auto operator()(First&& first, Second&& second, Rest&&... rest) const
    -> decltype( (*this)(boost::join(boost::make_iterator_range(begin(first), end(first)), boost::make_iterator_range(begin(second), end(second))), std::forward<Rest>(rest)...) )
    {
        return (*this)(boost::join(boost::make_iterator_range(begin(first), end(first)), boost::make_iterator_range(begin(second), end(second))), std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    }
};

constexpr join_type join {};
```

<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d41cd3bc5b47f2b0)</kbd>