# View containers as one

Tags: c++, c++14

The conditions are:

```
// A hierarchy
struct Base {
    virtual void everyone_has_this() = 0;
};
struct DA : Base {
    void everyone_has_this() override {...}
};
struct DB : Base {
    void everyone_has_this() override {...}
    void only_db_has_this() {...}
};

// And some vectors
vector<DA> das (3);
vector<DB> dbs (2);
```

I'd love to be able to use something like:

```
// Foreach all of them in one loop
for(Base& o : view_as_one<Base>(das, dbs)) {
   o.everyone_has_this();
}
// Or just several types of them
for(DB& o : dbs) {
   db.only_db_has_this();
}
```

The question is: is it possible?
If not, what are the other ways to one loop, instead of for each container?
Important is, I don't want to get rid of the **segregation** and **storage contigiousness.**

A dynamic_cast would work, if I used a single base pointer container, but it would involve checking for the type on every iteration, and the goal is to store all the objects in contigious storages.

---

Edit: **Alternative solution** if boost is not an option or view is not enough 
While I do love m.s.'s solution, because he implemented exactly the interface I asked for, I found that this interface I wanted, is not actually that flexible (can't use erase-remove).
So here's a different approach:

```
for_each_in_tuple(std::tie(das, dbs), [](auto& cont){
   for(auto& obj : cont) {
       // do what you want
   }
   // or even
   cont.erase(std::remove_if(begin(cont), end(cont), [](auto& obj) {
       // also do what you want
   }, end(cont));
});
```

- (-) Not as pretty
- (+) The iterator doesn't have to check which range it belongs to (faster)
- (+) It works even without virtual methods (because `auto&`).
- (+) Dependency only on `<tuple>` => no boost & compiles faster.
- (+) Not as restricted (e.g. can use erase-remove)
- (?) Not sure, but looks like msvc2015 can compile too.
  Note: 
  There are a plentiful of for_each tuple algorithms. I took this one:
  http://pastebin.com/6e8gmZZA

Comment: Which functions are shared through `Base` actually?

Comment: I would have another go at this question as I have not got a clue what you are trying to do

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, Say `virtual void foo() = 0`;

Comment: You need a combined container (references) with an iterator jumping from one container to the other for your `view_as_one`

Comment: @iwat0qs You may opt to hold your vectors a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` or `std::shared_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No segregation then (?). The goal was to be able to foreach a bunch of containers, or several, or just one arbitrarily.

Comment: @DieterLücking will answers given in that question work in OP case? From what I seen all answers require either same type for both containers or that references to them could be convertible between each other which is not the case for OP.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've edited my question. The linked solution(s) doesn't work. Still duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented using `boost::transform_iterator` and `boost::join`.

The following code uses Luc Dantons [variadic join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802088/678093) implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>


namespace ns {

// for ADL purposes
using std::begin;
using std::end;

struct join_type {
    template<class C>
    auto operator()(C&& c) const
    -> decltype(boost::make_iterator_range(begin(c), end(c)))
    {
        return boost::make_iterator_range(begin(c), end(c));
    }

    template<typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest>
    auto operator()(First&& first, Second&& second, Rest&&... rest) const
    -> decltype( (*this)(boost::join(boost::make_iterator_range(begin(first), end(first)), boost::make_iterator_range(begin(second), end(second))), std::forward<Rest>(rest)...) )
    {
        return (*this)(boost::join(boost::make_iterator_range(begin(first), end(first)), boost::make_iterator_range(begin(second), end(second))), std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    }
};

constexpr join_type join {};

} // ns


template <typename T>
struct ReturnTRef
{
    T& operator()(T& x) const { return x;};
};

template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Indices>
auto view_as_one_impl(Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    ReturnTRef<T> returnTRef;
    return ns::join(boost::make_iterator_range(boost::make_transform_iterator(begin(std::get<Indices>(tuple)), returnTRef), boost::make_transform_iterator(end(std::get<Indices>(tuple)), returnTRef))...);
}

template <typename B, typename... Args>
auto view_as_one(Args&&... args)
{
    return view_as_one_impl<B>(std::forward_as_tuple<Args...>(args...), std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}


struct Base {virtual ~Base(){}; virtual void talk() = 0;};
struct DA : Base {void talk() override { std::cout << "DA" << std::endl;} };
struct DB : Base {void talk() override { std::cout << "DB" << std::endl;} };


int main()
{
    std::vector<DA> das(3);
    std::vector<DB> dbs(2);

    for(Base& x : view_as_one<Base>(das, dbs))
    {
        x.talk();
    }
}
```

**output**

```
DA
DA
DA
DB
DB
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ce84c47fa397688)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just write some code to do this.

Simply implement `view_as_one` so that it meets the requirements for a C++ library container; or at least the minimum requirements needed to implement this functionality. Its constructor stores the references to the constituent, underlying containers. Implement its `iterator` class as iterating, in sequence, over each constituent container. Implement `view_as_one<T>::begin()` and `view_as_one<T>::end()`. Done.

I would expect to see this as a homework assignment in a typical "Advanced C++" programming class.

Comment: You just need to write class compatible with range-for loop. You do not need to implement Container requirements. (If you are looking in future, you might want to make it a Range)

Comment: @Sam Yeah, I understand that I would need a custom iterator for that, because there are no conversions between vector<Base>::iterator and vector<DA>::iterator.
But is it still possible, if view_as_one would take a variadic number of containers?
From what I believe, view_as_one would construct a sort of recursive template struct ?

Comment: @iwat0qs technically you can do that if all containers `value_type` have a common base. You can make a recursive template, or use commongly used in `tuple` multiple inheritance trick.

Comment: Yes, it is still possible if `view_as_one` takes a variadic list of containers. All that the variadic constructor needs to do is to save the pointers to the constituent containers (passed by reference) into the internal `std::vector` list of constituent containers. The implementation of `view_as_one` is agnostic as to the number of the constituent containers. If I were to give this homework assignment to my students, I would fail anyone who codes `view_as_one` for a specific number of containers, like 2 or 3. The right implementation must support any number of containers.

Comment: So, if I pass a `list`, `deque` and `vector`, what type stored pointers will be? I would expect to store list of containers as `tuple`, not `vector`.

Comment: A vector of smart pointers to an abstract class that implements `begin()` and `end()`. `view_as_one` constructs an implementing class for each constituent container (pushing each one into the vector) implementing `begin()` and `end()` as  returning smart pointers to an abstract iterator class that implements `operator*`, `operator++`, and `clone()` virtual methods. `view_as_one` then defines its iterator class and/or `begin()`/`end()` in the obvious manner.